# How to map through an array that contains hashmaps and find a matching key value pair

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
yolo = [
  { id: 1, description: 'yaya', count: '27' },
  { id: 2, description: 'it is', count: '27' },
  { id: 3, description: 'it ', count: '27' },
]
```

How do I return true when there is the same key value pair within the different hashes in the array. So in this instance I want this to return true because the count key value pair is the same in the multiple hashes. Thank you!

Comment: what about yolo = [ 
{id: 1, description: "yaya", count: "25"},
{id: 2, description: "yaya", count: "26"},
{id: 3, description: "it ", count: "27"}
]

Answer (score 0):

Is this satisfy you requirement?

```js
let yolo = [
    { id: 1, description: "yaya", count: "27" },
    { id: 2, description: "it is", count: "27" },
    { id: 3, description: "it ", count: "27" }
];

let other = [
    { id: 3, description: "yaya", count: "27" },
    { id: 5, description: "it is", count: "27" },
    { id: 6, description: "it ", count: "27" }
];


let exists = yolo.some(s => other.find(f => f.id === s.id));
console.log(exists);
```

Comment: You can add more conditions in find func, also.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious code might be to bubble search the `yolo` array for a repeated value in *any* of the arrayed object properties.

Code based on array methods would be a map/find/reduce + reduce approach (since you asked).

```js
yolo = [ 
{id: 1, description: "yaya",  count: "27"},
{id: 2, description: "it is", count: "27"},
{id: 3, description: "it ",   count: "27"}
];

// bubble find, early exit when repeated value found
var repeatFlag = false;

for (let i1 = 0; i1 < yolo.length && !repeatFlag; i1++) {
  let needle = yolo[i1];
  for (let i2 = 0; i2 < yolo.length && !repeatFlag; i2++) {
    let haystack = yolo[i2];
    if (i1 == i2) continue;
    for (let key in yolo[i2]) {
      if (repeatFlag = (needle[key] == haystack[key])) break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(`repeatFlag=${repeatFlag}`);

// map/find/reduce + reduce
var hasRepeat =
  yolo.map ((element,index) =>
    yolo.find((felement, findex) =>
      (index != findex)
      &&
      Object.keys(felement).reduce((acc, rkey) =>
        acc || felement[rkey]==element[rkey], false)
    )
  )
  .reduce ((acc, element) => acc || (element != undefined), true);
  

console.log(`hasRepeat=${hasRepeat}`);
```